# Send mouse position every 0.2 seconds pynput

Tags: python, pynput

I am using pynput to send my mouse position every 0.2 seconds.
I tried timing it:

```py
from pynput.mouse import Button, Listener as MouseListener

def on_move(x,y):
    global start_time
    time_passed = start_time - time.time()

    if time_passed >= 0.2:
        command = f'{None}\n{x}\n{y}'
        commands_q.put(command)
    start_time = time.time()

mouse_listener = MouseListener(on_move=on_move)
mouse_listener.start()
mouse_listener.join()
```

This code doesn't work. It crushes my program mid running (the program send the location of the mouse using sockets)

Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, but a simple code like this can work for you :

```
from pynput.mouse import Controller
import time
mouse = Controller()

while True :
    command = mouse.position
    commands_q.put(command)
    time.sleep(0.2)
```

For two listener mouse and keyboard both, use this kind of code :

```
from pynput.mouse import Controller as mouse_control
from pynput import keyboard as key_control

mouse = mouse_control() #mouse controller

def on_press (key) :
    print(key.char)

listener = key_control.Listener(on_press=on_press) #keyboard listener
listener.start()

while True :
    command = mouse.position
    print(command)
    time.sleep(0.2)
```

Comment: I can't do that because I need this process to happen at the same time with other things and threads won't work too for some reason

Comment: Why won't threading work ?

Comment: I think you are talking about simple thread in Python 2 module but threading module should work fine in Python 3

Comment: I have a keyboard listener as well. Can the Controller method be applied while having two listeners at the same time?

Comment: Yes it is possible, see my new code.